# Can I move to Australia? Special Category Visa... NZ/SA dual citizenship

Tags: australia, dual-citizenship, new-zealand, south-african-citizens, south-africa

I was wondering if anyone has come across this situation.

I would like to move to Australia on a special category visa.

I have a New Zealand passport and I have dual citizenship with New Zealand(by descent) and South Africa. I currently reside in South Africa and I will fly from here, and I have never visited or lived in New Zealand. I will go for a medical exam and check for TB before flying (because I know they are strict about this!)

I believe most New Zealand citizens are granted a special category visa but I’m not sure if they are referring to residents of New Zealand or if having lived in South Africa will be acceptable.

Thanks so much. Jay

Comment: The rights of New Zealand citizens in Australia are based on citizenship, not residency.

Answer (score 1):

You will be eligible for a special category visa upon arrival in Australia using your NZ passport. The only aggravating factors for that could be a criminal conviction. The fact that you have resided in South Africa won't have an effect on that.